# How to consider take the lowest value from each set of rows and find out their position?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have 2 big matrices of size 4700x1 and 100x1. I want to implement the following logic but I am not sure what can be the best way to implement it. I would like to explain that with a simple example.

Suppose I have 2 matrices of size 9x1 and 3x1.

```
A= 10
   20
   30
   50
   40
   60
   45
   30
   15
```

and

```
B=28
  22
  26
```

I want to compare each row of B with the matrix of A.There are 9 rows in matrix A and 3 rows in matrix B. when we are considering the first row of matrix B , we only need to consider the first 3 rows (row 1, row 2 and row 3) of matrix A and take the lowest value out of the matrix. Then again when we want to consider the second row of matrix B,  we will select the next 3 rows (row 4,row 5 and row 6).Similarly when we consider the last row of matrix B, we will consider the last 3 rows (row 7,row 8 and row 9) and take the lowest value from them. We need to put one variable called "K". When K=1, we will have to take one lowest value when we compare for each row of B and similarly when K=2, we will take 2 lowest values from each row of B and so on.

2. We also need to find the location of the lowest values.For matrix A, if we consider K=1 and we consider first 3 rows,then the lowest value is 10. So in that case, the location is (1,1). But when we consider the next 3 rows from A,then the lowest value is 40,but in that case I need the location as (1,2) and similarly for last 3 rows, the lowest value is 15. So the location is (1,3).

How to do it? Any suggestion will be very much helpful. Thank you very much.

It seems some of you guys are not able to understand what exactly I mean. Let me explain you with another example (as A and B are very small matrices). I am working on a technique called finger printing to estimate the position of a device in an indoor environment. On the above query,A is the matrix which consists of the Received Signal Strength (RSSI) values of reference points and B consists of the RSSI values of test points. Lets consider from the beginning with another example. 
Suppose there are 3 access points and I have a matrix of size 47x3 (lets assume there are 47 reference points),

```
A= [10,20,30;50,40,60;45,30,15;....;9,16,19]
```

Please note A is a 47x3 matrix. This matrix represents the RSSI values with respect to their access points. Lets check the first row the first row, this the our first point and the RSSI value with respect to Access point-1 is 10 then the RSSI value with respect to Access point-2 is 20 and the RSSI value with respect to Access point-3 is 30 and so on.This matrix represents the position of the reference points and the RSSI values with respect to all 3 access points.

Now lets assume we have another matrix of size 10x3 which consists of the RSSI and their location information about the test points named as,

```
B=[12,15,18;25,32,38;....;7,18,22]
```

Now I had to make take the Euclidean distance between each row of the test points with the whole matrix,for example: 
    sqrt((10-12)^2+(20-15)^2+(30-18)^2)
and then sqrt((50-12)^2+(40-15)^2+(60-18)^2)
.
.
sqrt((9-12)^2+(16-15)^2+(19-18)^2)

Now we have to consider the second row of B with all elements in Matrix A,

sqrt((10-25)^2+(20-32)^2+(30-38)^2)
and then sqrt((50-25)^2+(40-32)^2+(60-38)^2)
.
.
sqrt((9-25)^2+(16-32)^2+(19-38)^2)

and so on.

Now we will have a new matrix of size 470X1 (because we are considering one test point with all the reference points points at a time. So in this case we will have 47 values. Hence for 10 test points,we will have 470 values and now if we arrange them in a column then we will have a 470X1 matrix.)

I have done till so far and I need to work on this part below,
 Now we have to find out which is the lowest euclidean difference value for each test point. For an example, we have obtained out first 47 values (location 1 to 47) of matrix 470X1  from our first test point only. So in that case we only have to consider the first 47 values and obtain the lowest value from them and its position. Then for next set of 47 values (the location is same because we have a total of 47 locations only and this is another set which we obtained when we were considering the second test points.) that is from 48 to 94, we will have to find out another lowest value and its position.(Please note there are only 47 reference points, so the 48th value of 470X1 matrix is in location 1 again,49th in location 2 and so on).

In this case we have to use a variable "K" which will show us how many lowest values we have to take from 470X1 matrix and for 10 test points. If K=1, then we have to take one lowest value for each set of 47 values from 470X1 matrix. (For example, for test point-1, we have one lowest value from first 47 values, and then for test point-2,we have another lowest value from next set of 47 values and so on).
So we will have a total of 10 lowest values for 10 test points (We also need to know where they are).

Similarly for K=2, we will select 2 lowest value and we will have 20 lowest values in the end and so on.

If we select "K" as more than 1 then we have to take the average and then again we will get 10 values.

(This is what I want to know. I am not sure how to do this part).

Then I will estimate the error by taking the difference between the location of each test point and the location of our lowest euclidean distance value of that point.

Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I didn't quite get where B comes in. Is its value used for the minimum calculation? Also, in the example you use for each element of B, 3 elements of A. Is this the same number in your real application? 4700 is not divisible by 3

Comment: I didn't get what happens to `B` either. I also didn't understand the part about `K`. Please show us the output for your example above.

Comment: @brodroll I think you're supposed to take elements from `A` in groups of size `numel(A)/numel(B)` so that there are a total of `numel(B)` groups.

Comment: That's the same conclusion I arrived!

Comment: @brodroll , I have now made the modification to the question and now its more clear. please help. This method is called K mean method of the finger printing technique.

Comment: @beaker , I have now made the modification to the question and now its more clear. please help. This method is called K mean method of the finger printing technique.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and context. It is still not crystal clear to me. Could you share the code you have so far? Also: You shared with us an example A and B, which after your edit turned out to be a 470x1 and 10x1. So you look for the first 47 values for K minimum values, then search the next 47 for another K minimum values and so forth? And also store their position? Imo this is what both answers did! Could you show in terms of A and B more clearly the expected outcome? Also the K mean part is new. What you do to the positions stored since the values are averaged?

Comment: tl;dr... rather than show us the output for your existing example we get a wall of text.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below. You may think of what is your strategy if there are similar values in A.

```
clear all;

A = [10 20 30 50 40 60 45 30 15];
B = [28 22 26];

k = 1;

for ai = 1:numel(B):numel(A)
    A2 = sort(A(ai:ai+numel(B)-1));
    for ki = 1:k
        minA = A2(ki);
        locMinA = find(A(ai:ai+numel(B)-1) == minA);
        fprintf('ai = %d\tki = %d\tmin = %d\tlocation = %d\n', ai, ki, minA, locMinA);
    end
end
```

Output when k = 1:

```
ai = 1  ki = 1  min = 10    location = 1
ai = 4  ki = 1  min = 40    location = 2
ai = 7  ki = 1  min = 15    location = 3
```

Output when k = 2:

```
ai = 1  ki = 1  min = 10    location = 1
ai = 1  ki = 2  min = 20    location = 2
ai = 4  ki = 1  min = 40    location = 2
ai = 4  ki = 2  min = 50    location = 1
ai = 7  ki = 1  min = 15    location = 3
ai = 7  ki = 2  min = 30    location = 2
```

Comment: I have now made the modification to the question and now its more clear. please help. This method is called K mean method of the finger printing technique.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized approach:

```
[val loc]=sort(reshape(A,length(B),length(A)/length(B),1))
getk = @(x,y)(x(1:y,:)(:));
k=2; % Example value of k
getk(val,k) % Minimum values vector
getk(loc,k) % Minimum location vector
```

Where I assumed the 3 in your example was the ratio of the lengths of the two vectors. I also assumed B values were not used for the minimum values calculations.